# Do i still need a PTR Record when sending through a SMTP Relay like Simple Email Service?

Tags: debian

i currently have the issue that i have a pretty good server at home, but i'm conneted over a normal default ISP, so there is no way to set a ptr for my sometimes changing IP.

now i wanted to setup a mail server and i did it on a vps, but my issue is that the vps isn't that beefy and i actually dont want to spend so much for that little amount of storage while i got a beast at home with plenty of storage for my mails

Do i still need the PTR record even if the Mail comes from another SMTP Relay? ort is there any other solution that would allow me to host at home?

i'm currently using mailcow

Comment: As i guess, the exit node need to have a matching ptr record

Answer (score 1):

To receive mail, you don't need a PTR record.  However, to send mail servers connection to MX servers do need a pointer record.

Receiving mail on a dynamic IP address risks incoming messages getting lost when the IP address changes.  If you have I dynamic IP address, I recommend using a relay server for outgoing mail.

You could use your VPS server as an incoming and outgoing relay.  Set up spam checking on the VPS server so you can bounce spam before accepting it.  Have your home server send all outgoing mail to the VPS server to be relayed to the appropriate destination.  You would read emails from your home server.

Require authentication for the mail services running on your home server.  This includes SMTP, IMAP and POP.  Your VPS server should require authentication before accepting messages relayed to non-local addresses.  I would recommend using the Submission port (587) for authenticated connection to your SMTP server.

Comment: This is all good, but you didn't answer the question: is a PTR needed on both the originating server and the relay, or is it enough to have it on the relay?

Comment: @MayeulC PTRs are only needed on the relay. Unless it is an open relay, the Relay server will use other mechanisms to validate the server's legitimacy.  Normally, this will consist of requiring the server have an IP address in the Relay providers network.  This may be supplemented with a login mechanism.